# CommandID for 'Debug: evaluate' in Visual Studio Code not found

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, evaluate

I want to add a keyboard shortcut for the command 'Debug: evaluate' in Visual Studio Code. Unfortunately, the command ID for the command 'Debug: evaluate' is not documented. Did someone know where to find the commandId ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl` is what you are looking for. It will execute the current selected text in the debugger console.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/d2b6bbb46fbdf535e2c96b3e00ac56ac1d427a69/src/vs/workbench/parts/debug/browser/debugEditorActions.ts#L141