# Is there a shortcut in VSCode to execute current line or selection in debug REPL?

Tags: python, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I am developing with Python and commonly running code in an integrated terminal with `Shift` + `Enter`. However, when debugging the process seems to be more complicated. I need to copy the code, move focus to debug REPL (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Y`), paste, run and move focus back to the editor. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457051/how-to-return-focus-to-editor-in-vs-code-macro-sending-python-text-to-debug-cons/57788216#57788216

Comment: Have you tried the unbound command `editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl`?

Comment: So isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898660/commandid-for-debug-evaluate-in-visual-studio-code-not-found/38898981#38898981

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use the vscode's integrated debugging you can set a shortcut for sending selection to debug Repl. I use this on my `keybindings.json` config file:

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+d",
    "command": "editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl"
}
```

The difference from the `"workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText"` command is that you actually have to select the line to send to the debug Repl, does not work for just putting the cursor on the line and hitting the shortcut.

Comment: With `CTRL+L` you can select the line the cursor is on.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of VSCode, you can do it from the user interface.

Go to Settings, then Keyboard Shortcuts (or go there directly with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+K,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+,), then search for "Evaluate in Debug Console".

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Jump to Cursor" and that will cause the debugger to jump to that line next for execution; think of it as a GOTO statement. It's not the same as highlighting the code and sending it to the Debug Console, but should get you a similar result.

Comment: If understood correctly, not such exists in Visual Studio Code, only in Visual Studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552833/is-there-something-similar-to-set-next-statement-available-in-visual-studio-co

Comment: It might only be available in the latest version of the debugger which is still under experiment.

Comment: @Kotka turns out I got the command name wrong; it's "jump to cursor" and it should already be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

For those using MacOS:

- **Code -> Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts**

Top right icon to open `keybindings.json`:

[image]

And then paste something like this:

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "cmd+shift+enter",
        "command": "editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl"
    }
]
```